# Python, IDLE: Too many recursive errors

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error, python-idle, python-3.3

This is supposedly a problem with the IDLE editor for Python. (I'm running Python 3.3.0 on OSX, but the same problem occurs with 2.7.3)

I'm using IDLE to write Python programs. My problem is: Calling a recursive function, which calls itself too many times (1000 times), doesn't give me a single runtime error, but rather, it keeps sending me error messages until I close the program.

The error which it should be sending is: "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded."
The error which it sends a thousand times isntead is simply a point out to where in the script the problem is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#112>", line 1, in <module>
    factorial(1.5)
  File "/Users/User/Documents/Python/Scripts/program1.py", line 187, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n-1)
  File "/Users/User/Documents/Python/Scripts/program1.py", line 187, in factorial
    recurse = factorial(n-1)
```

etc.

This goes with all recursive functions calling itself too many times, but the specific function used here is:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result
```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401447/python-recursive-function-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177073/python-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded

Comment: It looks like IDLE is printing out every single stack frame (of which there are many). I don't know if there's a way to limit how many frames it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop python from showing those hundreds of errors, you can use a `try-except` block:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        recurse = factorial(n-1)
        result = n * recurse
        return result
try:
    print (factorial(6000))
except RuntimeError as e:
    print (e)
```

output:

```
#print factorial(1000)
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000

#print factorial(6000)
maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

In your case this error occurs because python has a limit on the maximum recursion depth,it is there to stop the C stack from overflow. But you can change it using `sys.setrecursionlimit`:

```
In [4]: import sys

In [5]: sys.getrecursionlimit()
Out[5]: 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a syntax error for an unknown reason.

Comment: @user2175018 python version? in py3.x use `print()` as a function.

Comment: Thanks, oversaw a missing (). Python 3.3.0

Comment: @kongehund what output do you expect here?

Comment: The error, which it gives me is: AttributeError: 'RuntimeError' object has no attribute 'message'

Comment: I'm not sure how it's supposed to work, but it currently simply outputs the message "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" when I launch the program. If I call factorial(6000), it still outputs tons of errors.

Comment: @kongehund I think you're not doing it properly, it works fine on my system and on ideone too. http://ideone.com/B611ng

Comment: That's odd, though. I copied the code on ideone, put it into a new script, yet when I do >>>factorial(6000), it still spams me with error messages. Thanks anyway

Comment: You've to put the call to `factorial` function inside the try-except, just calling `factorial(6000)` is always going to throw those errors.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I don't quite understand how, though. Final script: http://ideone.com/Ovysgi

Comment: Sure thing, it worked, but it fixed the function, rather than IDLE. Guess I'll have to use this every time I make a recursive function, then.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are trying to use a float and the code does not handle that. So, 1.5 -1 becomes 0.5, which causes the first recursive call. Then, 0.5 -1 becomes -0.5, which causes the further recursive calls.

Just in order to handle that, use:-

> if n<=0:  return 1

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm hoping to fix it, rather than avoid it.

Comment: Oh, well my problem isn't that I don't know what causes the errors, but rather, the fact that the program sends me 1000 error messages instead of 1. Adding your code to the function fixes the function, but I'm trying to make IDLE send me 1 error message instead of 1000, when it goes beyond the maximum amount of recursive calls.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question clearly explaining this

Comment: Oh, I thought my question was understandable. It should be clearer now, though.