# Maximum recursion depth error in Sympy when using non commutative symbols

Tags: python, runtime-error, sympy, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I have some big expressions which have their symbols with the attribute `is_commutative=False`.

Here is an example:

```
import sympy
from sympy import pi, sin, cos, exp
sympy.var('L, xPL, cosa, i, j, r2, sina, t, x', commutative=False)
sin.is_commutative = False
cos.is_commutative = False
exp.is_commutative = False


f = L*(r2 + sina*x)**(-1)*cosa*x*exp(10000.0*x*xPL*(2*i + 1 + i**2)**(-1)/L**2 \
    - 5000.0*xPL**2*(2*i + 1 + i**2)**(-1)/L**2 - 5000.0*x**2*(2*i + 1 \
    + i**2)**(-1)/L**2)*cos(pi*j*t - j*t**2/2 + pi*t - t**2/2) \
    - (r2 + sina*x)**(-1)*cosa*x**2*exp(10000.0*x*xPL*(2*i + 1 \
    + i**2)**(-1)/L**2 - 5000.0*xPL**2*(2*i + 1 + i**2)**(-1)/L**2 \
    - 5000.0*x**2*(2*i + 1 + i**2)**(-1)/L**2)*cos(pi*j*t - j*t**2/2 + pi*t - t**2/2)
```

If I try to do `f.simplify()` it raises an error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.
```

I already tried [the "gotcha"](http://mattpap.github.io/scipy-2011-tutorial/html/gotchas.html) `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but in this case it doesn't help.

What helps is to set `commutative=True` in `sympy.var`. (Without need to set it `True` to `sin`, `cos` and `exp`)

Since these expressions come from a previous process, I have the following workaroud:

```
def get_new_f(f):
    sin.is_commutative = True
    cos.is_commutative = True
    exp.is_commutative = True
    str_f = str(f)
    for s in f.free_symbols:
        sympy.var(str(x))
    return eval(str_f)r
```

Then `get_new_f(f).simplify()` works!

Is there another way to overcome this error?

Comment: I had a similar problem with recursion depth, [asked a question about recursion here once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526625/baktracking-function-which-calculates-change-exceeds-maximum-recursion-depth)and the only answer I've got was "because of the semantics of Python as a language, recursion isn't a particularly efficient paradigm" and a reference to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! the developers from SymPy says that recursion is a common practice for symbolic evaluation, but for this case I believe the problem is not the recursion, but the fact that the symbols are not `commutative`...

Comment: I didn't notice that you're setting is_commutative on sin, cos, and exp.  That isn't supported.

Comment: This error also happens when I don't do `.is_commutative=False` for `sin, cos, exp`...

Comment: @asmeurer despite it is not supported, setting `.is_commutative=False` for `sin, cos, exp` works very well to keep the order prior to the differentiation...

Comment: It shouldn't even be needed. These functions automatically inherit the commutativity of their arguments.

Answer (score 2):

With such a small expression, a recursion error like this most likely indicates a bug in SymPy. You should report this as a bug at the [SymPy issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/list).

Comment: Thank you, I will report it there. But it is important to say that this only happens when `is_commutative=False`

Comment: That's not surprising. There tend to be more bugs with noncommutative symbols because they aren't used as much.