# Fibonacci sequence: Recursion depth excess

Tags: recursion

Given the function to generate fibonacci numbers:

```
def fibonacci(x, memory = {0:0, 1:1}):
        if x not in memory:
                memory[x] = fibonacci(x-1, memory)+fibonacci(x-2, memory)
        return memory[x]
```

When I try some arbitrarily large number, say 4000th fibonacci number, I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What is the error caused by? What can be done as a work around without sacrificing the efficiency? I prefer this to iteration, since by iterating, calculating even the 50th position takes astronomically long for a computer (read: half a minute).

Comment: Iteration should significantly outperform recursion -- it doesn't sound right that it would take more than a smallish fraction of a second to compute F1 through F50.  Anyway, if this is Python, then you might want to look at sys.getrecursionlimit() and sys.setrecursionlimit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration is lot better than recursion in my opinion. Because

1. Iteration is lot more easily readable and traceable than recursion.
2. You can use concepts such as [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to reduce the memory load that may not be feasible with recursive functions.

As for what is Recursion Limit, you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit). It gives a basic explanation of what and why recursion limit is there. As shown there, you can give `sys.setrecursionlimit` to any value you desired.

Using iterator, this can be used for fibonacci series:

```
def fib(a, b):
    return b, a+b

for i in range(20):
    if i in (0, 1):
        print i
    else:
        print a
    a, b = fib(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others have mentioned you have hit the stack memory limit. You usually have a maximum of 50-100 maximum nested recursive calls before you hit this limit.

I think you might have a misconception about iteration (unrolling recursive functions)

```
def fib():
    a=0
    b=1;
    c=1;
    for x in range(4000):
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    print c;

fib();
```

There is no way this function would take longer than your recursive one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit the recursion limit. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401447/python-recursive-function-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded) is a link to a similar post, which might help. I would recommend that you use iteration, but I also came across this code to increase the stack size, but have not tested it:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) # change the '10000' to something that works
```