# Why do I keep getting the maximum recursion depth exceeded error?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing code for a number guessing game and it has to be sold by recursion. But when I execute it I get this error: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
import random
n = random.randrange(0,100)
guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))
def game(guess):
    if guess == n:
        print("Your guess is correct.")
    elif guess > n:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        game(guess)
    elif guess < n:
        print("Your guess is too low")
        game(guess)
game(guess)
```

Comment: Because you never get a new guess.  If the guess is too high or two low it just recurses forever.

Comment: @Sebastian Are you there? :) Please pick a correct answer. Only my answer has recursive function design. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game function don't need any parameter. You need to use `else` instead of last `elif` and `guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))` step should be in your game function (Tested):

```
import random
n = random.randrange(0,100)
def game():
    guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))
    if guess == n:
        print("Your guess is correct.")
    elif guess > n:
        print("Your guess is too high")
        game()
    else:
        print("Your guess is too low")
        game()
game()
```

Comment: That won't work well, if you're terrible at this game, you'll eventually blow the stack.

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm sure Sebastian's teacher wants a recursive function for his assignment :)

Comment: That would be a stretch. Recursion has no place here, I doubt any competent teacher would promote writing code in a way that is destined to fail.

Comment: @JeffMercado This is the basic assignment for understanding how a recursive function works. I saw it many times in engineering departments :)

Comment: Ah, I missed the part in the question that says recursion is required (sorta).  Anyway, there's better ways to teach recursion, and this is not the use case for it. Oh well.

Comment: I managed to fix this. I'm dumb and I didn't notice I wasn't asking for a new input so it kept looping with the first guess so it would obviously crash. But I've managed to fix it, I even managed to add a guess counter so it's all good. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, unless `guess` is equal to `n` the first time you call the function, you have an infinite recursion because you call `game` with the same value of `guess`. You don't provide any way to stop the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`maximum recursion depth exceeded` occurs because of the infinite loops when `guess > n` , `guess < n` condition is meet.
To know further refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401447/python-recursive-function-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded).

The below code should work as expected.

```
import random,sys
n = random.randrange(0,100)

def game(guess):
    if guess == n:
        print("Your guess is correct.")
        sys.exit()
    elif guess > n:
        print("Your guess is too high")
    elif guess < n:
        print("Your guess is too low")

while True:
    guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))
    game(guess)
```

Comment: I think Sebastian's teacher wants a recursive function for his assignment :) Then your answer is not good for him :D

Answer (score 0):

1. You need use `random.randint()` function like this: `n = random.randint(0, 100)`.
2. Use a `while` loop is recommended.
3. You didn't call `guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))` again.

---

```
import random
n = random.randint(0, 100)
guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))

def game(guess):
    while guess != n:
        if guess > n:
            print("Your guess is too high")
        elif guess < n:
            print("Your guess is too low")
        guess = int(input("Introduce a number: "))

    else:
        print("Your guess is correct.")

game(guess)
```