# What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this excercise:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=12

Unfortunately, I receive the error message:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

The programm first calls the divisor-function, then calculates the triangle number for n, then checks whether the number is prime or not, and if it is, it directly checks the triangle number for n+1 because there is no prime number with 500 divisors by definition. If it isn't a prime nunmber, it is supposed to check the divisors of the triangle number as long as I haven't found 500 of them.

```
def triangle_number(n):
    tri_number = int(n*(n+1)/2)  # calculate triangle number for n
    return tri_number


def divisors(n):
    tri_number = triangle_number(n)
    if isprime(tri_number) is not True:  # check if triangle number is prime
        counter = 0
        while counter < 500:  # as long as we don't have enough divisors
            for x in range(1, tri_number+1):
                if tri_number % x == 0:     # check every triangle number for
                                            # their divisors
                    counter = counter + 1
                divisors(n+1)  # if for-loop breaks, check the next tri number
    else:
        divisors(n+1)  # do the same if the number is already prime


def isprime(n):
    [...]


def main():
    print(divisors(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python recursive function error: "maximum recursion depth exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401447/python-recursive-function-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded)

Comment: Recursive calls aren't free, and each layer of recursion takes up space in memory.  If you're running up against the recursive depth limit, that's a pretty clear sign that you're trying to recursively solve a problem that doesn't need to be approached in that manner.  Try an iterative solution.

Comment: Won't solve issue, but `if not isprime(tri_number):` or `if isprime(tri_number) is not True:` rather than the comparison to `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is not a functional programming language (although it has some functional parts in it).

Therefore, recursion has not a complete funcionality inside Python, there is a recursion depth limit. That's the error you're facing. You hit the recursion depth limit.

Try to implement this using function calls and loops instead of using recursion.

See [Python Recursion Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)